# jquery empty not working

Tags: jquery, input

Anyone see why this wouldnt work as intended!?

```
$('.project_ref_input').val().empty();
```

I've tried with .text() and just with .empty()...no luck!?

.project_ref_input is the class of the input

This is the complete jquery code:

```
$('.project_ref_input').live('change',function(){ 
                var project_ref_input=$(this).val();
                $(this).next().replaceWith("<p>" + project_ref_input + "</p>");
                $('.project_ref_input').val().empty();
            });
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It doesn't work because `val` doesn't return a jQuery object, but a string. To set a value, pass it to `val` as the argument. try:

```
$('.project_ref_input').val('');
```

Answer (score 1):

Or:

```
$('.project_ref_input').removeAttr('value');
```

http://api.jquery.com/removeAttr/

Answer (score 0):

Try by removing .val(), since .val() returns string, we don't have empty function available for string is javascript